# Switch off Fabric on-demand after Fabric is initialised?

Tags: privacy, google-fabric

Is there a way to disable Fabric once it's initialised? We want to have a toggle in our app to switch off in-app tracking once the user has enabled it to comply with the new GDPR data protection regulations.

Using Crashlytics `2.6.7@aar`, Fabric gradle plugin `1.+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. There isn't a runtime kill switch for the Fabric SDK. If you have a toggle that allows a user to change their settings after initializing Fabric, I suggest that you add a warning to the user that they need to restart the app for the setting to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for this! Found a workaround to restart the app on demand using Jake Wharton's Process Phoenix library :). Any plans to add to the SDK an opt out API?

Comment: Anytime and for the SDK, it's not on our immediate roadmap to add in.